# How to allow user to review worksheet using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

My macro generates a series of reports that are 60 columns wide. I want users to be able to review the reports on screen before printing them or going on to another segment of the macro.

it there a way to set a scrollarea, have user review it, and then have the respond to a message box to continue the routine?

I tried this:

```
Sub reviewdata()

' Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Fin. Stmts").ScrollArea = ""

Application.Goto Reference:="monthlydata"
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Worksheets("data. Stmts").ScrollArea = "monthlydata"

If MsgBox("End Review", vbOKOnly) = vbOK Then
End If
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
Worksheets("data. Stmts").ScrollArea = ""

End Sub
```

the problem is that once the if, then statement is executed the user can not move around the worksheet since the routine needs a response to continue.

any insights are most appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Why not break it into two macros with a button on the sheet to execute step 2? Example is first macro generates report, then user hits button that executes the print/final steps?

Answer (score 1):

**You can Use a Dummy Variable:**

```
Dim dummy As Range

Set dummy = Application.InputBox("Scroll and Check. After That Select Ok!", "This is Specially created so that you can", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
```

Input Box that Takes in Range Allows you to Scroll in Background. Keep hitting `Ok` in and nothing will change, code will run as it is running at the moment.

Comment: Your's was First, and Nobody Copied anyone's :)

Comment: thanks much. will try out suggestion and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clumsy but it sort of gets what you want. Instead of using a MsgBox use and InputBox as a range, which will allow the user to click around and scroll, as you describe. Whenever they hit okay/cancel, the macro will continue.

So probably replace your MsgBox line of code with....

```
Dim boom As Variant
boom = Application.InputBox("When you're done hit ""Cancel""... (""OK"" might lead to problems...)", _
    "Scroll around and look at stuff", _
        , , , , , 8)
```

I would recommend doing two macros instead, but this probably does what you need.

Comment: Hehe.. I reached to the same Work Around. You might want to use `Set` as `8` is the Range Input.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that message in a small userform and call that userform in `modeless` state as shown below.

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

This way you will be able to navigate in the sheet with that message still showing.

[image]

You can also put the rest of the code in the button click event as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    Worksheets("data. Stmts").ScrollArea = ""
    Unload Me
End Sub
```